# bitcoinjs - mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)

Tags: multi-signature, javascript, bitcoinjs, bip174-psbt, ordinals

[image]

I'm trying to follow the below transaction example by magic eden and extend it to support multiple buyers and seller (in red). However I am having difficulties when I add more than one signature from another party (with one seller it broadcasts okay). The transaction builds and signs fine but when I try to broadcast it to the network it results in the error `mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)`. Using native segwit addresses for this (no-tr).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Using the bitcoinjs library here is what I have so far (only the red):

Seller signing:

```
let psbt = new bitcoin.Psbt({ network });

const [ordinalUtxoTxId, ordinalUtxoVout] = ordinalOutput.split(":");
const tx = bitcoin.Transaction.fromHex(await getTxHexById(ordinalUtxoTxId));

try {
    tx.setWitness(parseInt(ordinalUtxoVout), []);
} catch {}

const input = {
  hash: ordinalUtxoTxId,
  index: parseInt(ordinalUtxoVout),
  nonWitnessUtxo: tx.toBuffer(),
  witnessUtxo: tx.outs[ordinalUtxoVout],
  sighashType:
    bitcoin.Transaction.SIGHASH_SINGLE |
    bitcoin.Transaction.SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY,
};

psbt.addInput(input);

psbt.addOutput({
  address: paymentAddress,
  value: price,
});
```

Buyer Signing (ignoring padding inputs and outputs):

```
// Add inscriptions inputs and outputs
for (const signedPsbt of sellerSignedPsbts) {
    // Add inscription output
    psbt.addOutput({
        address: receiverAddress,
        value: signedPsbt.data.inputs[0].witnessUtxo.value,
    });

    // Add payer signed input
    psbt.addInput({
        ...signedPsbt.data.globalMap.unsignedTx.tx.ins[0],
        // ...signedPsbt.data.inputs[0],
        witnessUtxo: signedPsbt.data.inputs[0].witnessUtxo,
        // nonWitnessUtxo: signedPsbt.data.inputs[0].nonWitnessUtxo,
        // finalScriptWitness: signedPsbt.data.inputs[0].finalScriptWitness,
    });

    input++;
}

// Add seller payment outputs for payee
for (const signedPsbt of sellerSignedPsbts) {
    // Add payer output
    psbt.addOutput({
        ...signedPsbt.data.globalMap.unsignedTx.tx.outs[0],
    });
}
```

Merge seller and buyer signed psbts:

```
const buyerSignedPsbt = bitcoin.Psbt.fromBase64(signedBuyingPSBTBase64);

for (let index = 0; index < signedListingsPSBTBase64.length; index++) {
    const sellerSignedPsbt = bitcoin.Psbt.fromBase64(signedListingsPSBTBase64[index]);

    buyerSignedPsbt.data.globalMap.unsignedTx.tx.ins[BUYING_PSBT_SELLER_SIGNATURE_INDEX + index] = sellerSignedPsbt.data.globalMap.unsignedTx.tx.ins[0];
    buyerSignedPsbt.data.inputs[BUYING_PSBT_SELLER_SIGNATURE_INDEX + index] = sellerSignedPsbt.data.inputs[0];
}

// broadcast buyerSignedPsbt
```

Regtest Base64 psbt

Seller Signed 1
cHNidP8BAFICAAAAASOmBfmvfvsLtR13NFmTe7a1PqExPjrG3n11nxrkWj8tAQAAAAD/////ATBuFgAAAAAAFgAUWFy3jcqHhb9Q8bNzCelM6HJWOowAAAAAAAEBH4gTAAAAAAAAFgAUWFy3jcqHhb9Q8bNzCelM6HJWOowBCGwCSDBFAiEAzLuOeIyXt/12KDkqD+mGRj105SHJHC1HdshaQ0fg0ocCID2ZxLyTs4NLZvynw5dKIrXetdQv+J0S9KrMJuznDJFRgyEDYTg80B9Vdeb/4anKg9DSL98+B2HsIPk6jUQNJEKFadEAAA==

Seller Signed 2
+PSZaCbgm2ZSnbSI9pFk/2DFLekqsj91nGUx2AQAAAAD/////ATBuFgAAAAAAFgAUWFy3jcqHhb9Q8bNzCelM6HJWOowAAAAAAAEBH4gTAAAAAAAAFgAUWFy3jcqHhb9Q8bNzCelM6HJWOowBCGsCRzBEAiA686mylIphxLrBDMStAv3a5srPBlXkSbsFMtUPIS/04QIgBooAkEWVhDcpJdNToJpO8GmF+Tv9bTqxNLjKbBCxc0ODIQNhODzQH1V15v/hqcqD0NIv3z4HYewg+TqNRA0kQoVp0QAA

Buyer Signed
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

Merged TX (Giving error)
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

Comment: Can you also share the transaction itself?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Sorry for the delay, I have updated the post with regtest psbt txs. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: For completeness, can you also share the final serialized transaction that produces the error?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Added the final merged transaction giving the error.

Comment: The PSBT you've added doesn't seem to be finalized. Can you post the _actual final raw transaction_ that Bitcoin Core error on when you pass it so `sendrawtransaction`?

Comment: That is the final one? Is it missing something because on https://bip174.org/ it appears to display correctly. All the final script witnesses of the inputs are present?

Comment: The final transaction should not be a PSBT anymore but a normal bitcoin transaction in hexadecimal format.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated the post with the hex tx that was broadcast.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad I know it can be done, just wondering what I am doing differently compared to this transaction.

https://mempool.space/tx/1c37709bb3956cf0afb019f4e81072ec03e6cff6033f8932ed872495aaef6f83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Figured it out, basically everything was correct except for the padding of the inputs to make the seller psbt (1 input and 1 output) line up in the same position.

For example:

```
Input 1 - 3000   Output 1 - 9000
Input 2 - 3000   Output 2 - Input 4
Input 3 - 3000   Output 3 - Input 5
Input 4 - 10000  Output 4 - To Seller 1 (Seller PSBT 1, need to be inline with Input 4) 
Input 5 - 10000  Output 5 - To Seller 2 (Seller PSBT 2, need to be inline with Input 5)
Input 6 - Price  Output 6 - Change
```